# Unwanted symbol ă in tabular environment

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table using the tabular environment using this code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Scenario}} \\ \hline
                This & 15 \\ 
                Is  & 10  \\
                Example & 100  \\ 
            Tabular  & 10 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This works fine for this MWE, but in my own document the result has strange added symbols in the table. All the symbols are the same: ăăăăă.

Does anyone have a solution? I've been struggeling with this for quite some time and tried a few things myself without success. The MWE I has no issues, still I would like like to know if someone has expierenced the same issue before.

Comment: I'm not getting the errors you're talking about.  Could you give a minimal working example as per Werner's suggestion.

Comment: Ok I will do it know :)

Comment: I have edited the post to represent a MWE

Comment: @Martijn: This is still not a MWE. Please make it selfcontained.

Comment: Ok done, but in the MWE I have no issue, still I would like like to know if someone has expierenced the same issue before.

Comment: @Martijn: By definition, you _have to have_ the issue in the MWE, otherwise it's not a MWE. (The "working" in "minimal working example" is a little misleading, it should be something like "not working" or "buggy".) Have a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: You probably have a "NO-BREAK SPACE" character in your input; since you don't load `inputenc`, this character produces the glyph in position `0xA0` which, in a T1 encoded font, is precisely "ă". Try loading `\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}` and you'll get error messages about it.

Comment: @doncherry: I know what a MWE is.

Comment: @egref, thank you! Could you tell me how this can be fixed?

Comment: @egref: adding \usepackage[ascii]{inputenc} does fix the issue, but I get a lot of error messages for my entire thesis. However, the tables look fine in PDF. Is there a quick and dirty way without having to adress all the errors indicated by this package?

Answer (score 2):

I get the problem when the document is encoded as Latin-1 and a "NO-BREAK SPACE" character is used (as between the letters X, Y and Z)

```
% -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
X Y Z
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the file is UTF-8 encoded, the same input gives

[image]

The fact is that if `inputenc` is not loaded, the "NO-BREAK SPACE" character typesets the glyph in the current font that's T1 encoded (if `fontenc` had not been loaded nothing would have been printed) and in position `0xA0` there is precisely an "ă".

With the following modification

```
% -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
X Y Z
\end{document}
```

running LaTeX would give something like

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `ascii'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 X?
      Y?Z
```

which might help you in zapping the offending character.

Comment: Thank you for your explenation. I do however have an additional question before I can solve the issue. You are saying "zapping the offending character", does this mean I need to delete some character or put a ~ somewhere? What would be a bad character in my 'MWE'?

Comment: I cannot post my own answer, but removing the indents in the tabular environgment resolved the issue for my specific document class. Allthough I find this very supprising, it did the trick.